# Adding link after remove in last child

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I want append link add in last child of class:(`('.' + change_class + ':last .adda .mediumCell:first')`) after remove, but if you remove last chil (`44444444444444444444`), it not append in last child mean `3333333333333333333` and remove with same row, how can fix it?

**Example from my code:** http://jsfiddle.net/LX49c/1/

```
$('.remove').live('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var change_class = $(this).closest('.find_input').find('div').attr('class').split(" ")[0];
    var url = $(this).closest('.find_input').find('div').attr('class').split(" ")[1];
    var get_class = $(this).closest('.' + change_class).attr('id');
            $('#' + get_class).fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $(this).remove();
            });
            $('.' + change_class + ':last .adda .mediumCell:first').append('<a href="" class="add_input">add</a>'); 
});
```

Comment: It's better to add 'add link' after list. It's easier but it's only my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `append(...)` to within the `.fadeOut` function. See http://jsfiddle.net/LX49c/2/

```
$('.remove').live('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var change_class = $(this).closest('.find_input').find('div').attr('class').split(" ")[0];
    var url = $(this).closest('.find_input').find('div').attr('class').split(" ")[1];
    var get_class = $(this).closest('.' + change_class).attr('id');
            $('#' + get_class).fadeOut('slow', function () {
                $(this).remove();
                $('.' + change_class + ':last .adda .mediumCell:first').append('<a href="" class="add_input">add</a>');
            });
            //Moved from here
});
```

An alternative method is to remove the class before appending: http://jsfiddle.net/LX49c/4/

```
....
var get_class = $(this).closest('.' + change_class).attr('id');
        $('#' + get_class).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $("#" + get_class).removeClass(change_class);
        $('.' + change_class + ':last(-1) .adda .mediumCell:first').append('<a href="" class="add_input">add</a>');
```

---

You're doing multiple expensive JQuery calls. I'd suggest replacing the following code:

```
var change_class = $(this).closest('.find_input').find('div').attr('class').split(" ")[0];
var url = $(this).closest('.find_input').find('div').attr('class').split(" ")[1];
//Replace the previous by:
var className = $(this).closest('.find_input').find('div').attr('class').split(" ");
var change_class = className[0];
var url = className[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the link *before* the remove. You are starting an animation that will remove the element when it's done, but the animation won't start until you exit the function.

If you want to append *after* the remove, you have to put that code in the event handler that is executed after the animation is done:

```
$('.remove').live('click',function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var change_class = $(this).closest('.find_input').find('div').attr('class').split(" ")[0];
  var url = $(this).closest('.find_input').find('div').attr('class').split(" ")[1];
  var get_class = $(this).closest('.' + change_class).attr('id');
  $('#' + get_class).fadeOut('slow', function () {
    $(this).remove();
    $('.' + change_class + ':last .adda .mediumCell:first').append('<a href="" class="add_input">add</a>'); 
  });
});
```